# django admin enable sorting for calculated fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following two fields in my db table and model (Model Name: Order):

```
id, branch_id, product_id, cost, quantity, status, ordered_at
```

And I have the following code in my OrderModelAdmin:

```
list_display = (
    'order_number',
    'branch',
    'product',
    'cost',
    'quantity',
    'calculated_total',
    'status',
    'ordered_at',
)

def calculated_total(self, obj):
    return obj.cost * obj.quantity
calculated_total.short_description = _('Total')
```

Now, I want to enable sorting for this field. In reality, all I need to do is to add a column in my SELECT statement:

```
 SELECT (t.cost * t.quantity) as TOTAL
 ORDER BY TOTAL
```

Is there a way I can append an SQL statement for sorting in Django Admin?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It isn't possible to order by the result of the `calculated_total` method.

However, you can set the default ordering for your model admin by overriding the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method for your model admin, and [ordering by an expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#some-examples) that calculates the same thing.

```
class OrderModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(OrderModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.order_by(F('cost')*F('quantity'))
        return qs
```

A similar approach is to annotate the queryset with the total, and then order by that field. Assuming that cost is a `DecimalField` and quantity is an `IntegerField`, you need to use `ExpressionWrapper` to set the output field. See the docs on [Using F() with annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) for more info.

I don't think it's possible to use `total` directly in `list_display`. However, you can alter your `calculated_total` method to access the annotated field. We set `calculated_total.admin_order_field = 'total'` so that the Django admin allows you to sort on that column by clicking on it.

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, DecimalField

class OrderModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'number', 'price', 'calculated_total']

    def calculated_total(self, obj):
        return obj.total
    calculated_total.admin_order_field = 'total'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(OrderModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(total=ExpressionWrapper(F('cost')*F('quantity'), output_field=DecimalField())).order_by('total')
        return qs
```

Comment: I used annotation and it worked properly and it makes sense but the code above needed some tweaking. I had to add `calculated_total.admin_order_field = 'total'`. Realistically, this is exactly what I was looking for. To be able to add a custom column and and sort that field based on that column. Thank you!

Comment: @Gasim good point! My original answer sorted the queryset by total by default. You need to set `admin_order_field` if you want to be able to click on the column to sort by it. I've added that to the answer.